# Oracle Connection Issue with Gridview

Tags: asp.net, oracle, gridview, connection

I try to connect a oracle database in asp.net. I want to handle connection with SqlDataSource. When I use the code below, I get the following error:

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system
>   can not find the file specified.
>
> Source Error:
>
> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system can not find the file
>   specified.]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not
>   open a connection to SQL Server)]

Here is the aspx file:

---

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org  /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:SqlDataSource
        id="SqlDataSource1"
        runat="server"
        DataSourceMode="DataReader"            
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM PERSON "
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OracleConnectionString %>">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>


    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" BackColor="WindowFrame" AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true">

        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Numarası" DataField="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Adı" DataField="NAME" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Soyadı" DataField="SURNAME" />

        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>

    <br />

</div>       
</form>
```

---

But I can connect database directly, besides I can connect it with another code file , with the procedure below:

```
    private void ReadOracleTypesExample(string connectionString)
    {
        OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        try
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM PERSON";
            OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();


        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                OracleString oraclesring2 = reader.GetOracleString(1);
                Label2.Text += ("<br />" + oraclesring2.ToString());

                OracleString oraclestring3 = reader.GetOracleString(2);
                Label3.Text += ("<br /> " + oraclestring3.ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
        }
        reader.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Label1.Text = e.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

---

---

The oracle database is accessible by the tools outside the c#. I could not imagine why I can not connect to the database, I will run off the rails. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try setting the ProviderName property of your SQLDataSource.  The default is SQL Server.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.providername.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the SqlDataSource control to connect to an Oracle database, you must configure your SqlDataSource.

1 From the Data tab of the Toolbox, drag a SqlDataSource control onto your page.

2 If the SqlDataSource Tasks smart tag does not appear, right-click the control and click Show Smart Tag.

3 In the SqlDataSource Tasks list, click Configure Data Source.

4 In the Configure Data Source dialog box, click New Connection.

5 The Choose Data Source dialog box is displayed.

6 In the Data source list, click Oracle Database and then click Continue.

7 The Add Connection dialog box is displayed.

8 In the Server name box, type the name of the Oracle server.

9 Type the user name and password to connect with the database.

10 Make sure that the Yes, save this connection check box is selected, change the name of the connection string if you want, and then click Next to have the connection string information saved in the application's Web.config file.

11 The Configure the Select Statement pane appears.

12 Click Next.

13 Click the Test Query button to test your query against the database, and then click Finish.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Even though I edit necessary modifications in source style,it seems my edits are not sufficient.The changes done by the visual studio 2012 is: in web.config:     <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=localhost;Password=123456;User ID=TAHA"
      providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />

Comment: I'am happy to help you Varoluscu Here you have different format of string connection :http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: My first connection string is being got from there, but it didn't worked as seen above.

Comment: Varoluscu what'is your exception message ? the same or a new exception

Comment: My exception, as written in my first post,  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system can not find the file specified.

Source Error:

[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system can not find the file specified.] >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

Answer (score 0):

> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]

It seems like that you have problem with your connectin string. Your page cannot connect to the database.

I use following connection string:

> add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Password=123456;User ID=TAHA";Unicode=True" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" />